# Can't access another domain's valid json with jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to access a JSON api of a certain adult-oriented website, but I can't get it to work. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SSqwd/ and here is the code:

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&search=sex&thumbsize=big&page=1&output=json&callback=?',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I get

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

even though when I browse to the page myself and check the json on jsonlint, it is perfectly valid.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: There must be better ways to get porn ?

Comment: Change the `dataType` to `'jsonp'`.

Comment: adeneo I'm trying to _build_ a better way to get porn. While learning about javascript.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, that doesn't fix it.

Comment: @user1624005: Their API doesn't support JSONP.  Therefore according to the Same Origin Policy, you can't read it.  The only way to get the data in your JavaScript is to proxy the AJAX call through your server.  Have JavaScript send an AJAX request to your server which gets the data from the API.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, I always thought it was JSON or JSONP that you could do, just not XML.

Comment: @user1624005: Browsers can only access data via AJAX from the same domain the site is running on (unless you're using CORS), the format of the data is irrelevant.  JSONP is a hack in which a script tag is added to the page, and the returned "JSON" is wrapped in a function call, so it's ran like a script.

Comment: So is JSONP not an acronym for "JSON with Porn"? :)

Comment: @bfavaretto: That's a special type of "padding", if you know what I mean ;)

Comment: And here I was, thinking I was making a "Just send over nice porn" request.

Comment: @bfavaretto - You wish!

Comment: @user1624005: You are making that kind of a request, but the server doesn't like the "P"... if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you specified a cross domain request jQuery will by default attempt to request that URL using JSONP even though you've only set the dataType to JSON. So what actually happens is the following script tag is added to the DOM:

```
<script src="http://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&search=sex&thumbsize=big&page=1&output=json&callback=?" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(the ? actually gets replaced with a function name jQuery generates)

Your browser then tries to execute the returned data. However, as it is not actually JSONP and is just pure JSON what it returns is invalid javascript and hence you get the Syntax error.

You can reproduce the same error by just using:

```
<script src="http://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&search=sex&thumbsize=big&page=1&output=json&callback=?" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And doing nothing else. Or you can copy and paste the response from that URL  and wrap it in script tags, you'll get the same error thrown.

The only way to solve this error is use an API that supports JSONP or implement a sort of proxy that requests the data via your own server on the same domain.